# What distribution shape does this broadband signal have if the bandwidth changes?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, simulations, signal-processing, photonics

In the Lumerical tool, I'm simulating a setup using a broadband dipole signal. It is (or should be) centered at $\lambda=$ 922.5 nm and has various bandwidths $\Delta \lambda$ for different simulations. Below, you see the signal as it is submitted to the simulation region for $\Delta \lambda=$ 100 nm (first three graphs) and $\Delta \lambda$ = 500 nm (last three graphs) respectively.

[image][image]

I have two questions about this:

1. Why is the signal no longer centered at $\lambda$ = 922.5 nm, especially for larger bandwidths? (FYI: the fourth graph is maximal at $\lambda$ = 857 nm)
2. What distribution shape does the 'spectrum vs wavelength' graph have?

Comment: It's hard to address this unless we know what you did to the signal.  What is the nature of the device?

Comment: The dipole is embedded in a semiconductor (InP) nanowire; the material properties are modelled with empirical frequency dependant electric permittivities (and thus refractive indices, $n$ = 3.45 for $\lambda$ = 922.5 nm). I've disabled the imaginary part of the complex electric permittivity, so the material is dispersionless/lossless. The boundary conditions of the simulation region are all PML (absorbing any incoming radiation/energy). I'm interested in finding resonances in the structure around the bandgap frequency/wavelength.